# Enabling autosave on Sublime Text Editor

Tags: macbook-pro, text-editor, sublimetext

I am using the Sublime editor on Mac. But I have to manually save the file. And when the editor is closed it asks whether to save the file or not. Is there a way to make it behave like Notepad++?
**Desired Behavior:**
Sublime Text should close without asking anything and when reopened it should preserve the open texts files
**Things I tried:**
Opened Settings and added hot_exit: true but this didn't have any effect.
The following pic shows the settings:
[image]

Comment: Is this really about Apple software, hardware or services?

Comment: How are you quitting it? If it cmd-q then it closes without prompting but restores everything on reopening. I'm using the defaults, and not overriding either hot_exit, or save_on_focus_lost.

Comment: I am clicking on the red round cross button